# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'A'

Tags: python, pandas, invalidation

When i want execute this python code :

```
rfm_bank_promotion_analysis = pd.read_pickle('/content/rfm_bank_promotion_analysis.pickle')
rfm
```

But get this error message :

> UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 rfm_bank_promotion_analysis = pd.read_pickle('/content/rfm_bank_promotion_analysis.pickle')
> 2 rfm
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in
> read_pickle(filepath_or_buffer, compression, storage_options)
> 206                     # We want to silence any warnings about, e.g. moved modules.
> 207                     warnings.simplefilter("ignore", Warning)
> --> 208                     return pickle.load(handles.handle)
> 209             except excs_to_catch:
> 210                 # e.g.
>
> UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'A'.

Please help, Thanks.

I was expecting the table from data set